# codigo tachado en react js - redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vscode, redux

Estoy haciendo un curso de react y voy por la parte que empezamos con un poco de redux. Lo que no entiendo es por que cuando importo `createStore` y despues cuando creo el componente llamado asi, aparecen tachadas las palabras (no se cual es el termino correcto para decirle a eso). Adjunto fotos.

[image: screenshot del codigo]

Si no me equivoco es la primera vez que me ocurre, el codigo funciona bien, pero me da intriga y no se si esta mal que aparezca asi.

Muchas gracias!

Comment: Está "deprecado", eso es lo que significa que esté tachado. De hecho me imagino que si pasas el ratón por encima y ves la documentación que muestra te dirá eso mismo (*deprecated*) y alguna alternativa a usar. Eso significa que es un método que ya no debería de usarse porque no tiene soporte, y es muy posible que en futuras versiones se elimine directamente. Lo correcto cuando un método se queda obsoleto (que es la traducción de *deprecated*, aunque muchos usamos el spanglish "deprecado") es utilizar las alternativas que proponen en vez de dicho método.

Comment: ahh claro en el mismocodigo me lo decia. perfecto muchas gracias!